# Php 5.6 opcache not showing up in Mac Sierra

Tags: php, macos-sierra

I've made the possible changes to the php.in at /etc/php.ini. I didn't had php.ini so took a copy of php.ini.default. The changes I've made are

```
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=64
```

When I print phpinfo() and see the result, I tried to find opcache and it is not showing up. I'm using Mac Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have edited the correct php.ini (it can be seen in the phpinfo() result).
Check, if the files listed in "Additional ini files parsed" does not override your settings. (e.g.: opcache.enable=0 somewhere override your php.ini setting)

If you are using PHP-FPM, that need a restart / reload to pick up the changes.

Comment: When I try to find the php.ini using the command: php -i | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
I have only one php.ini

Comment: Additional ini files parsed is none.

Comment: I am not familiar with mac builds, but can you make sure the extension is loaded correctly? 
zend_extension=opcache.so
is in your php.ini